# Add double tap to code

Tags: android, imageview, gestures

the following is my Main Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import com.barr.survey.R.id;
class Demo {
public static String roomname;
}
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
static int TAKE_PICTURE = 3;
Uri outputFileUri;
LinearLayout L1;
ImageView image;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
private static final String STATE_SCALE = "state-scale";
private static final String STATE_CENTER_X = "state-center-x";
private static final String STATE_CENTER_Y = "state-center-y";
private GestureDetector detector;
DBAdapter db;
EditText mEdit1;
EditText mEdit2;
private ImageView mImage;

public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
    Button txt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.picbtn);  
    Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/heydings_edit.otf");  
    txt1.setTypeface(font2);
    Button txt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn);  
    txt2.setTypeface(font2);
    Button txt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailbtn);  
    txt3.setTypeface(font2);
    Button txt4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.micbtn);  
    txt4.setTypeface(font2);
    Button txt5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitbtn);  
    txt5.setTypeface(font2);
    String imagename = "DSC00277.png";
    String destDir = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() +
            "/databases/";
    String destPath = destDir + "surveydata.db";
    File f1 = new File(destPath);
    if (!f1.exists()) {
        //---make sure directory exists---
        File directory = new File(destDir);
        directory.mkdirs();
        //---copy the db from the assets folder into 
        // the databases folder---
        try {
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("surveydata.db"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {        
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageAsset(imagename);
        if (savedInstanceState != null && 
                savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SCALE) &&
                savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_X) &&
                savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_Y)) {
            imageView.setScaleAndCenter(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_SCALE), new PointF(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_X), savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_Y)));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(DemoActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Could not load asset", e);
    }}
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(id.imageView);
    outState.putFloat(STATE_SCALE, imageView.getScale());
    PointF center = imageView.getCenter();
    if (center != null) {
        outState.putFloat(STATE_CENTER_X, center.x);
        outState.putFloat(STATE_CENTER_Y, center.y);
    }}
public void capscr(View view) {
           Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
           saveBitmap(bitmap);
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Screenshot Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
           public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
               View rootView = findViewById(R.id.container).getRootView();
               rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
               return rootView.getDrawingCache();
            }
           public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
               String schname = "fred";
                String[] tokens = schname.split(" ");
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                String ref = "mark";
                final String imageFileName = "Room" + "-" + ref + "-" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
               File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + imageFileName);
                FileOutputStream fos;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    //Put up the Yes/No message box
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder
                    .setTitle("Send Screenshot")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                    
                            emailtext2(imageFileName);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)                      //Do nothing on no
                    .show();
                   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
                }  
            }
           public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) 
                throws IOException {
                    //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                }
public void savetext(View view) {
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String name = "survey.csv";
    File file = new File(path, name );
    String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String fileName = String.format("%s/" + "survey" + ".csv", path);
    String site = "site";
    String building = "Building";
    String Floor = "Floor";
    String RoomRef = "RoomRef";
     mEdit2   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String Notes = mEdit2.getText().toString();
    TextView data1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String filenamestr = data1.getText().toString();
    String Line = site + "," + building + "," + Floor + "," + RoomRef  + "," + filenamestr + "," + Notes + lineSep;
    try {
            File myFile = new File(fileName);
            if(!myFile.exists()){
            myFile.createNewFile();
            }
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile,true);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(Line);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRR", "Could not create file",e);}}
public void testbtn(View view) {
    room(Demovar.roomname);
}
public void takepic(View view) {
        String schname = "fred";
        String[] tokens = schname.split(" ");
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = tokens[0] + "-" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        TextView detail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        detail.setText(imageFileName); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String name = imageFileName;
            File file = new File(path, name );
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE); 
            new SingleMediaScanner(this, file); 
   }  
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 1;
public void speech1(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
    case RESULT_SPEECH: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            editText.setText(text.get(0), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);   
        }
        break;
    }
    case 109: 
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    editText.setText(result.get(0), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);  
          }
    case 2:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);   
        }
    case 3:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
                bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(outputFileUri, this);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Setting image image icon on the imageview
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this
                    .findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
        }
            break;
        }
    }
public void clk_exit(View view) {
    System.exit(0);
}
public void emailtext(View view) {
    File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/survey.csv");
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Survey Data");
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mark.barr@sodexo.com"});
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Survey Data Attached");
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(myFile.toString())));
         intent.setType("text/plain");
         this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
}

public void emailtext2(String filenamestr) {
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String name = "/" + filenamestr;
        File myFile = new File(path, name );
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Screenshot");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mark.barr@sodexo.com"});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Map Screenshot Attached");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(myFile.toString())));
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
}
public void room(String roomid){
db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    String strname = roomid;
    Cursor c = db.getAsset(strname);
    if (c.moveToFirst())        
        DisplayContact(c);
db.close();
           }
public void DisplayContact(Cursor c)
{
String fontPath1 = "fonts/DistProTh.otf";
Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath1);
TextView a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sitename);
a.setTypeface(tf2);
a.setText(c.getString(1));   
TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Building);
b.setTypeface(tf2);
b.setText(c.getString(2));
TextView d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Floor);
d.setTypeface(tf2);
d.setText(c.getString(3));
TextView e = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Roomno);
e.setTypeface(tf2);
e.setText(c.getString(4));
TextView f = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Drawref);
f.setTypeface(tf2);
f.setText(c.getString(5));
 }}
```

I want to be able to double tap somewhere in the imageview and it to then do something

My code for the double tap is as follows

```
detector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override

            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            int x = (int)ev.getX();
            int y = (int)ev.getY();

            SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            PointF sCoord = imageView.viewToSourceCoord(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
            if(sCoord.x > 1940 && sCoord.x < 2119 && sCoord.y > 1558 && sCoord.y < 1719){Demovar.roomname="141"; };
            if(sCoord.x > 2120 && sCoord.x < 2322 && sCoord.y > 1558 && sCoord.y < 1719){Demovar.roomname="142";};
            if(sCoord.x > 2323 && sCoord.x < 2520 && sCoord.y > 1558 && sCoord.y < 1719){Demovar.roomname="143";};
            return true;
            }
```

I cant for the life of me work out where I can add the code to make it work i keep getting errors

Please excuse me if this is an obvious question i'm really new to gestures

Any help is appreciated

Mark
UPDATED CODE

```
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);

    final GestureDetector gestureDetector =  new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());
    mImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                   }
               });
```

this code gives the errors below
Mark

Comment: Have you assign the listner to teh ImageView ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the touch listener to invoke the `GestureDetector`

```
 GestureDetector gestureDetector =  new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
     imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                });
```

So, you code will look like :

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);

        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,
                new GestureListener());
        mImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }

    private class GestureListener extends
            GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        // event when double tap occurs
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();

            Log.d("Double Tap", "Tapped at: (" + x + "," + y + ")");

            return true;
        }
    }
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531025/2591002)

Comment: Thank you for this Any Idea where I insert it in the main activity whereever I put it i get errors

Comment: in `OnCreate` of `MainActivity`

Comment: I put it after Super.onCretae and it depriciates Gesture Detector says that Context cannot be resolved to a variable then GestureListener cannot be resolved to a type Then Imageview cannot be resolved to a type then OnTouch Listner cannot be resolved to a type then  onTouch(View, MotionEvent) of type new OnTouchListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method Then gesture detector Cannot refer to a non-final variable gestureDetector inside an inner class defined in a different method so Many errors I cant get my head round it

Comment: I have added code in main activity above to show where errors are

Comment: You need to Create `GestureDetector` class